Can i get marketing cloud's domain in journey builder custom activity
We are developing custom activity.
I want to distinguish between org calling custom activity by this domain.

so, i used req.header.host
but This method fetches the domain of the server where custom Activity is uploaded.
Can i get marketing cloud's domain when custom Activity is loaded?

This is a XY Problem - you shouldn't need this domain. Please edit your question and describe what you're trying to accomplish.

I can give you the theory. Have not had the chance to do it myself.
Hope this helps in some form anyway:

The shown domain (s.xx) is not uniquely identifying your org.
It identifies the stack (data center) where a LOT of orgs are hosted.

To uniquely identify your org, you are looking for is the MID / accountID of your Business Unit. Which is the actual "context" your app will be executed in.

Custom Content Blocks, JB Activities do not run "in" Marketing Cloud but on an external server. They are simply embedded, and they do not "know" who embeds them unless you do some pretty involved back-and-forth (hidden iframe...):


https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/content-builder-block-sdk/build-a-custom-block

It seems this is outdated, judging by the comments here on triggerAuth2() Authenticate Custom Content Block via SFMC - but the referenced repo DOES describe the newer triggerAuth2() method: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk

quoting from there:

triggerAuth2({authURL: authURL, clientId: clientId, redirectURL: redirectURL})
Opens a hidden iframe to the OAuth2 page for the authURL provided. Passes an OAuth2 code to the block’s server-side redirect URL so it can request a token.
Parameters
Name  Type    Description Required
authURL   string  The enhanced package authURL (auth_uri) in string format    X
clientId  string  The enhanced package clientId (client_id) in string format  X
redirectURL   string  The enhanced package redirectURL (redirect_uri) in string format    X
scope string array    An array of permissions being requested in [string, string] format

Once you have a token, you can get the "context" MID out of it using:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/gettokencontext.html
Addt. information
if you get the authenticated user, you can retrieve more information about them using
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getUserInfo.html
getUserData(callback(:dataObject))
Gets some context for the currently authenticated user. The updated data object is passed into a callback function.
Parameters
Name    Type    Description Required
callback(:data) function    Receives some object data about the currently authenticated user (object)
Notes
The object argument of the callback contains a stack and locale property.

Thank you for your kind reply.
Is there a way to dynamically import sub-domains if I don't know sub-domains during the app installation stage?

Not directly. Stack and MID are property of the Account proper, the sub-domain you see is part of (technically optional) Sender Authentication Package. The subdomain wouldn't be a suitable unique Id for your context though. SubD. is mutable, could be nonexistent, could be 1 SubD to 1 Business Unit; for sendouts, there could even be 1 BU :n SubdD. What you can do is enter such info as a property of the Account / BU into a configuration / environment variables table. E.g. Heroku comes with options to enter Config Vars. Then you can retrieve it by something dynamic like AccountId.
